# Javac in bash script returns no such file

Tags: java, bash

Im trying to make a shell script that compiles and runs a certain .java file. The java program works, I only have trouble with the bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
CWD=$(pwd)
CLSPATH="$CWD/Program.java"
COMMAND="javac -classpath $CLSPATH"
eval $COMMAND
java Program
```

in this form the error is

```
javac: no source files
```

so I changed the COMMAND variable to

```
COMMAND="javac\ -classpath\ $CLSPATH"
```

but this way I get

```
./runJava.sh: line 6: javac -classpath /home/dorin/LocationWhatEver/Program.java: No such file or directory
```

But the file and directory exist. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the actual file to compile - instead you're passing the `.java` file as the classpath.  Your actual command looks something like this:

```
javac -classpath /some/dir/Program.java
```

while it should be something like this:

```
javac -classpath /path/to/library.jar /some/dir/Program.java
```

I think you're missing the actual classpath somewhere.  Most likely your script needs to be similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
CWD=$(pwd)
CLSPATH=/path/to/library.jar
SOURCE="$CWD/Program.java"
COMMAND="javac -classpath $CLSPATH $SOURCE"
eval $COMMAND
java Program
```

Also, I'm not sure what the purpose of the `eval` approach is.  Why not just invoke `javac`?  I would further modify the script to be:

```
#!/bin/bash
CWD=$(pwd)
CLSPATH=/path/to/library.jar
SOURCE="$CWD/Program.java"
javac -classpath $CLSPATH $SOURCE
java Program
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and I also learned something! Thanks a lot for your time mate!